# Fake bank account class

Tags: c++, finance

I just some reviews on how I can make it more efficient or cleaner and what I should fix in general.

```
class bankAcc
{
public:
    bankAcc() = default;
    bankAcc(string fn, string ln) : firstName(fn), lastName(ln) {}
    bool createUser(istream &is);
    bool login() const;
private:
    bool correctLogin(const string&, const string&) const;
    static vector<string> usernames;
    static vector<string> passwords;
    string firstName, lastName;
    string username, password;
};

vector<string> bankAcc::usernames;
vector<string> bankAcc::passwords;

bool bankAcc::createUser(istream &is) {
    is >> username >> password;
    if (is.fail()) {
        cout << "Invalid option" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        return false;
    }
    usernames.push_back(username);
    passwords.push_back(password);
    return true;
}

bool bankAcc::login() const {
    bool login;
    string tempUser, tempPass; 
    cin >> tempUser >> tempPass;
    if (cin.fail()) {
        cout << "Invalid options" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        return false;
    }
    login = correctLogin(tempUser, tempPass);
    if (login == true) {
        cout << "Logged on" << endl;
        return login;
    }   
    else {
        cout << "Incorrect info" << endl;
        return login;
    }
    return login;
    }

bool bankAcc::correctLogin(const string &tempUser, const string &tempPass) const {

    if (usernames.empty() || passwords.empty())
        return false;
    bool usernamePassed, passwordPassed; int cnt = 0;
    for (auto c : usernames) {
        if (tempUser == c) {
            usernamePassed = true;
            break;
        }
        else {
            usernamePassed = false;
        }
        ++cnt;
    }
    if (passwords[cnt] == tempPass && cnt < passwords.size()) {
        passwordPassed = true;
    }
    else {
        passwordPassed = false;
    }
    return usernamePassed && passwordPassed;
}
```

Comment: Note: You should **never** store the actual password. You don't actually need it for validation. Store a hashed version of the password. Then when a user logs in you hash the password they pass and see if it matches the stored hash.

Answer (score 2):

I have a few suggestions:

In your constructor, you are passing in `string` by copy when it is completely unnecessary to do so. You should pass these in by const reference:

```
bankAcc(const string &fn, const string &ln) { /*...*/ }
```

Also, this constructor should check whether or not `fn` or `ln` are clean inputs (i.e. they're valid first and last names). You can do this like so:

```
bankAcc(const string &fn, const string &ln) 
{
    if (fn == "" || ln == "")
        throw std::invalid_argument("Can't have empty names");
    firstName = fn;
    lastName = ln;
}
```

Speaking of `firstName` and `lastName`, I don't see a use for them here at all as they're only used in the constructor and nowhere else. Is there a need for them?

You should also practice the `Principle of Sole Responsibility` here. In other words, each class should have only one single responsibility to take care of. Your class is called `bankAcc` yet it really seems more like a `BankAccountLoginValidator` class to me. Your class isn't doing anything that a bank account should be doing (no balance, no withdrawal/deposit schemes etc). Moreover, you should generally separate I/O operations from the validation code in this class. Have the caller of the class objects perform the I/O and then have them use your class to validate their input. Your class should *not* be responsible for I/O.

Finally, your use of two vectors to store the user-name and password is inefficient since you end up spending `O(n)` time searching for the right username in the `usernames` vector. Instead, look at using a hashtable to store this information instead. A hash-table in C++11 is called `std::unordered_map`. Then, your lookup operation can be done in `O(1)` amortized time. With this map, your correct_login() function becomes unnecessary.

Here's your code refactored a bit:

```
class bankAcc
{
public:
    bankAcc() = default;
    bankAcc(const string &fn, const string &ln)
    {
        if (fn == "" || ln == "")
            throw std::invalid_argument("Error! Can't have empty names");
        firstName = fn;
        lastName = ln;
    }
    bool createUser(const string &user_name, const string &pass_word)
    {
        if (user_name == "" || pass_word == "")
            return false;
        /* Maybe add more validation code here */
        // ....

        uname_to_pass.insert(user_name, pass_word);
    }
    bool login(const string & user_name, const string &pass) const
    {
        return uname_to_pass[user_name] == pass;
    }

private:
    static unordered_map<string, string> uname_to_pass;
    string firstName, lastName;
    string username, password;
};
```